# React Github page is not updating

Tags: css, reactjs, github, updating

So I managed to set up my website through the gh-page repository, however I need to make changes to various elements, such as responsiveness, but the changes are not updating. My page still looks the same prior to the changes.

What am I doing wrong?

My repository is https://github.com/MannyLerma/portfolio-main

I tried updating, copying-pasting builds and other files and I've tried merging pull requests and such, but I am failing to understand where the issue lies. Am I just not being patient enough? I saw online that changes usually take about 10 minutes to take effect, but I've waited past this.

Comment: Did you run deploy command again after changes?

Comment: I ran it after you posted this, but nothing has changed

Comment: Did you run build before deploy?

Comment: it can take github pages a minute to propagate changes. Maybe try loading in a incognito window or clearing cache / cookies? Give it an hour after building and deploying?